# Adding MSSQL spatial layer using Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, spatial-query, sql-server-spatial

I'm having difficulty adding a MSSQL spatial data layer using Python. The database is password protected, and I can add the layer without any problems using the built in feature, but I can't make it work with a Python script.

I have been trying to follow the advice on [this website](http://nathanw.net/2011/06/07/opening-ms-sql-server-2008-spatial-tables-in-qgis-correctly/) without any success.

Using the following script (except with the actual variables obviously) gives me a 'Invalid layer' error every time and I have tried with various different syntax:

```
uri = "MSSQL:server=xx.xx.xx.xx,database='MYDBNAME',user='MYUSERNAME',PWD='MYPASSWORD',tables=dbo.MYTABLENAME"
qgis.utils.iface.addVectorLayer(uri,'newlayer','ogr')
```

I'd also like to be able to run SQL queries on this as well.

The advice on the qgis website explains how to load just about every other type of layer except MMSQL (http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html)

Comment: -Have you looked at the log from SQL Server management studio?

-I also believe the separator in the ogr connection string is a ; and not a ,
like: MSSQL:server=.\MSSQLSERVER2008;database=dbname;trusted_connection=yes

Comment: Have the same error:
Tested your two lines of code on my MSSQL and QGIS 2.01 on W7 64 bit, results in a in a QGIS crash. The crash creates a windows dmp files. Viewing the dump file in Visual Studio states a exception information: "The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access."

Using the same settings with the QGIS button 'Add MSSQL Spatial Layer' works fine.